# Tether Android Phone to Raspberry Pi (for MMS/SMS)

Tags: raspbian, usb, android, gsm

I recently got a RPI coming from the land of Arduino, and I was wondering as I've been searching Google for this has anyone found a way to tether their phone to their Pi. I'm looking to use my phone as a way to send MMS/SMS, so basically my RPI will send a signal to the phone via the usb wire to transmit some data via SMS. I'm looking into this as it will be more robust in my case than using a 3G USB Modem - since I won't need the USB powered adapter, etc. (I would assume this is possible except I haven't gotten around to trying it since I only have rev A with 1 usb port which I am using for keyboard/mice, and I'm awaiting B in the mail, so I thought I'd ask to see if there is a good way to go about doing this possibly.)

Comment: Are you planning to have SMS messages only sent to your phone, or anyones phone?

Comment: Other users phones will receive the text msg, so each phone would have to be set to send txt only to a specific number. Alternatively I have considered sending from multiple devices to the same remote phone with a unique id and then the clients can simply access their specific msgs via server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQJwz8xL9gQ) explains the process quite well.  However, it uses email to send a SMS message instead of tethering to a phone:

1. Make sure you can use the `mail` command (`sudo apt-get install mailutils`) and [setup your Raspberry Pi to send emails from the command line](http://iqjar.com/jar/sending-emails-from-the-raspberry-pi/).
2. You need to look up [the SMS gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) for the phone you want to send an SMS to.  An example of a number converted to an email would be `1234567890@vtext.com` (for Verizon).
3. Send the email/SMS: `$ echo “Test text” | mail -s “Test Mail” 1234567890@vtext.com`

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the answers you have so far which are not very useful.
They have all missed the point that you do not have an internet connection.
I am wanting to do the same thing as you. Have you found a solution?