# Receiving messages from my phone

Tags: wireless, display

I'd like to have my Raspberry Pi receive messages from my (i)phone.

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/tether-android-phone-to-raspberry-pi-for-mms-sms) is kinda the opposite of what I want.  I want to send a text message (possibly to an email) to parse on my raspberry pi.  I'm very new to raspberry pi but just ordered a wifi dongle.

After I receive the message I want to just output it onto a screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some carriers allow you to text an email address from a phone.  After that it's a simple matter of having a ruby or python script check the email address for your text/command/whatever on a regular interval.

Comment: yeah i can text an email, but how do I set the raspberry pi to display it

Comment: guess maybe that's not suited for this SE, oops

Comment: @TMP: As I said, a scripting language like ruby or python could then be used to check the web address every given time interval.  For example, Ruby has the IMAP library below.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html

Comment: awesome, i'll give that a shot.  I just saw this question which is a similar way to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338129/email-checking-and-then-act-upon-script-for-reacting-to-a-sms-message